# SQL Server 2008 setting user login details for DB and Web.Config

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hey I have a DB Settings in web.config as follows

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="server=serverName;database=dbName;user=dbuser;pwd=dbpass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Whats best practice for the username and password ? Is it best to just make up a stronger password i.e Iu5jku23 something like that ?

And then in SQL Server 2008 what are the best settings for the user at the moment my sql user has

```
db_datareader
db_datawriter
db_owner
db_securityadmin
db_accessadmin
```

anyone ones I should remove ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Examples of Strong SQL Server passwords:**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/965823)

- Does not contain all or part of the
  user's account name
- Is more than eight characters in
  length
- Contains characters from at least
  three of the following categories:
- English uppercase characters (A
  through Z)
- English lowercase characters (a
  through z)
- Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
- Nonalphabetic characters (for
  example: !, $, #, %)

As far as setting permissions, it really depends on how granular you want to get and how limited you want your attack surface area to be.

Setting db_owner basically allows that user to do anything.  So if this particular "account" only needs to read data and show it on a webpage, than datareader would be your best, most secure choice.

So as most things, it depends on what you are doing.

Comment: Should be able to read, insert and update data thats about it

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to not store the pwd in plain text.  Always use a strong password and encrypt it, or use Integrated Authentication.

Regarding the database roles, with db_owner the rest are redundant.

**Edit:**
Regarding encrypting web.config: have a look here **http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx**.  You should give the user only what they need.  The user will need execute permissions on the stored procedures and read/write to any underlying tables the procs touch as appropriate.  db_datareader will allow read access to everything in the database, likewise with db_datawriter (only it's write access there obviously).

Comment: Can you desribe how I can encrypt the password in web.config. Also you mean I only need to tick db_owner and that will be fine ? Im not sure if this user needs so much permission as I only need to be able do basic SQL stuff from my web app i.e run stored procedures